# Oracle SQL compare dates to list

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a list of model, serial, dates (the dates do not exist in the DB). I need to pull model, serial, and most recent call dates prior to the dates given to me. I did find a "solution" that worked using CASE but was wondering if there is a simpler way. When having a list of a 100+ items the OR CASE statements are a bit grueling to work with.

```
SELECT   M.MODEL_NBR, DEV.SERIAL, i.c_date 
  FROM   device dev, 
         model m, 
         A_DEVICE ad, 
         INTR i 
 WHERE   (DEV.SERIAL, i.intr_id) IN 
            (select serial, max(t.intr_id) over (partition by t.part_id)
               from intr t, device d
              where t.part_id = AD.PART_ID 
                and d.device_id = ad.device_id
                and d.model_type = 'XX'
                and d.serial in ('1234', '5678')
                and (1 = (case 
                          when d.serial = '1234'
                           and t.c_date < to_date('10/10/2014', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
                          then 1
                           end)
                  or 1 = (case 
                          when d.serial = '5678'
                           and t.c_date < to_date('11/11/2014', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
                          then 1
                           end)))
         AND M.MODEL_ID = DEV.MODEL_ID 
         and M.MODEL_NBR = '1111' 
         AND DEV.DEVICE_ID = AD.DEVICE_ID 
         AND AD.PART_ID = I.PART_ID 
         order by DEV.SERIAL;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `CASE` in the `WHERE` clause is almost always better represented as `AND/OR` expressions. In this case, instead of:

```
and d.serial in ('1234', '5678')
and (1 = (case 
           when d.serial = '1234'
                and t.c_date < to_date('10/10/2014', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
           then 1
           end)
      or 1 = (case 
              when d.serial = '5678'
                   and t.c_date < to_date('11/11/2014', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
              then 1
              end)))
```

You'd be better off using:

```
and ((   d.serial = '1234'
         and t.c_date < to_date('10/10/2014', 'mm/dd/yyyy'))
     or (d.serial = '5678'
         and t.c_date < to_date('11/11/2014', 'mm/dd/yyyy'))
```

---

Alternately, you could use a CTE to make a pseudo-table using your values:

```
WITH serial_values as (
     select '1234' as serial, to_date('10/10/2014', 'mm/dd/yyyy') as c_date from dual
     union all
     select '5678' as serial, to_date('11/11/2014', 'mm/dd/yyyy') as c_date from dual)
SELECT   M.MODEL_NBR, DEV.SERIAL, i.c_date 
  FROM   device dev, 
         model m, 
         A_DEVICE ad, 
         INTR i 
 WHERE   (DEV.SERIAL, i.intr_id) IN 
            (select serial, max(t.intr_id) over (partition by t.part_id)
               from intr t 
                    cross join device d
                    join serial_values sv
                    on d.serial = sv.serial
                       and t.c_date < sv.c_date
              where t.part_id = AD.PART_ID 
                and d.device_id = ad.device_id
                and d.model_type = 'XX')
         AND M.MODEL_ID = DEV.MODEL_ID 
         and M.MODEL_NBR = '1111' 
         AND DEV.DEVICE_ID = AD.DEVICE_ID 
         AND AD.PART_ID = I.PART_ID 
         order by DEV.SERIAL;
```

Comment: Seems they all return data in about the same time, but I think your solutions look or feel a bit cleaner. Maybe I over thought that one. Thanks.